# How does $ln(y) = 2x+C$ become $y = e^{2x+C}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I'm working with Simple First Order differential equations in linear algebra, and from this lecture slide, my teacher somehow went from $\ln(y) = 2t+C$ to $y = e^{2t+C}$.

I'm unsure of how to get to $e$. Do I multiply the $\ln$ out? Do I divide it? No matter what I do I can't get to that same function.

Comment: Take the exponential of each side to get $e^{2t + C} = e^{2t}e^C = A e^{2t}$, since $e^C$ is just any constant. Of course $e^{\ln y} = y$. Lastly, use the IC to get $A$.

Comment: Ah alright. So are we multiplying the left-hand side by e?

Comment: AHHH I see, we are taking e to the power of ln y on the left side, which results in y, and e to the power of 2t + C on the right, which results in what we have so far. Now I see. Thanks!

Comment: In other words, $e^y$ and $lny$ are inverses of each other with the needed restriction of domains.

Answer (score 1):

You neither multiply nor divide but you compose the functions. That gives

$$\ln(x)=\underbrace{y}_{id}\iff \underbrace{e^{\ln(x)}}_{=(\exp\circ\ln)(x)}=\underbrace{e^y}_{=(\exp\circ id)(y)}\iff x=e^y$$

where $id$ is the identity. Then, you get

$$\ln(y)=2x+C\iff e^{\ln(y)}=e^{2x+C}\iff y=e^{2x+C}.$$